Extremely slow blockchain syncing issue on RaspBerry Pi 4 with Raspiblitz
I'm encountering a significant delay in synchronizing the blockchain on my Raspberry Pi 4. Even after 11 days, the sync progress is only at 68%. I'm using a brand new Raspberry Pi 4 with a 1TB USB 3.0 drive and a 400mbps wired internet connection. Despite adjusting various settings in my bitcoin.conf file, I haven't seen any improvement in syncing speed.
I've ensured the wired connection is stable, and the hardware seems to be functioning properly.
I am getting less than 10 peers, usually dropping off to around 3.
Blocks are estimated to be coming in every 2 seconds on average.

Does this answer your question? bitcoind sync time incredibly slow also see Raspiblitz slow sync performance
